# Отличие между рейдом и гаванью

Tags: семантика

Чем отличается рейд от гавани?

Answer (score 1):

Эти слова не имеют общих значений. Гавань - это часть водного пространства, географический объект, который можно увидеть на карте. Рейд - место расположения конкретного корабля. Подробнее можно пролчитать [в толковых словарях](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?game=x&all=x&word=%E3%E0%E2%E0%ED%FC).

Comment: alt+0151 = тире.

Comment: @shampar О, нашёл у себя на планшете: —, —, сейчас потру эти комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

Гавань — защищенный от ветра и волн участок побережья, который может использоваться для стоянки, разгрузки или ремонта судов. Это может быть как бухта, так и участок берега, защищённый искусственно насыпанными молами. Гавань, оборудованная причалами и подъездными путями, называется портом.

Рейд — место якорной стоянки судов внутри гавани или порта (внутренний рейд) или на подходах (внешний рейд).